# Http Network Operation Request in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am noob in Android. As you know for making network request (WebAPI call) then you get the `HttpClient` and `HttpResponse`, `HttpPost` these connections whenever you make any Web API call and after all done then you shutdown this http connection.

So If you require to make 50+ WebAPI  calls at different time for your application Is this good idea to create `httpclient` everytime and do processing then close then repeat same process for other request.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadIssueUrlStr + "/patrol-api/issues");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<NameValuePair> nameValueParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValueParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("patrol_sid", patrolIdPar));
nameValueParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isuDescription", descriptionPar));
nameValueParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isuDate", datePar));
nameValueParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isuTime", timePar));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValueParams));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
String mApiResponse = null;
mApiResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I know already about Volley and Retrofit that does good job for you, but please let me know answer of my question.

Comment: Using Volley might be easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `Volley`.
It can handle request queues.

[Video](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) intro.

[Demo](https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo) codes.

If you still want to use `HttpClient`, you should create a static instance of `DefaultHttpsClient` and use the same one every time.

Comment: pls see my question again.

Comment: What you will have to do is create a static instace of httpClient and use that for every async request. For that async request use asynTask : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html .

Tell me if that makes sense.

Comment: That fine but good question here If I use single instance of it what would happen if I am doing two network call at the same time ? will it work according to you

Comment: Yes, it will. Default executor for Async task is serial executor.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpClient Optimization Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html)

> Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application

[HttpClient Threading Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html)

> During execution each method uses an instance of an HttpConnection. Since connections can only be safely used from a single thread and method at a time and are a finite resource, we need to ensure that connections are properly allocated to the methods that require them. This job goes to the MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager